# Javascript if and for loop confusion

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm creating a Pig Latin translator and this function below checks for a double consonant.

Everything runs great up until it checks the word more in the function.  It outputs the second letter as "m" as well.  After that word the function seems to malfunction the word smile outputs the first and second letter to the console as "st".  What confuses me is the last word in the array "string" ends up with the correct output to the console "st".

If anyone can look over my code and see something that I'm not seeing, I would be grateful. My JSFiddle is below.

```js
var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
var consonant = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

doubleConsonate();

function doubleConsonate() { // add the sent as a parameter
  var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", "a", "few", "more", "smile", "its", "a", "string"];
  console.log("the word or phrase: " + theSent);
  var consonantCount;
  for (var i = 0; i < theSent.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < consonant.length; j++) {
      if (theSent[i].slice(0, 1) == consonant[j]) {
        console.log(theSent[i]);
        console.log("1st letter being checked is:  " + theSent[i].slice(0, 1));
      } else if (theSent[i].slice(1, 2) == consonant[j]) {
        // consonantCount = true;
        console.log("2nd letter being checked is:  " + theSent[i].slice(1, 2));
      } //else if (consonantCount == true) {
      //theSent[i] = theSent[i].slice(2) + theSent[i].slice(1,2) + "ay";
      //consonantCount = false;
      //}
    }
    //console.log(consonantCount);
  }
  console.log(theSent);
}
```

Comment: The second `m` is from `smile`.

Answer (score 0):

The second `m` is coming from `smile`, which is the word after `more`.

When `theSent[i] == "more"`, it loops through the consonants. When it gets to `m`, it matches `theSent[i].slice(0, 1)`, so it logs

```
more
1st letter being checked is: m
```

Since the second letter isn't a consonant it never gets logged.

Then the outer loop continues with `theSent[i] == "smile"`. When it loops gets to `consonant[j] == "m"`, this doesn't match `theSent[i].slice(0, 1)`, but it does match `theSent[i].slice(1, 2)`, so it logs:

```
2nd letter being checked is: m
```

You don't log `theSent[i]` before this, so it wasn't obvious that it was a different word.

The basic problem is that you're looping through the consonants, checking each of them against the first and second letter. This means you'll show whichever letter is the lowest consonant. If you want to tell whether a letter is a consonant, you shouldn't have that loop, just test whether the letter is in the array using `indexOf()`.

Also, instead of `.slice()` you can use subscript notation to access specific characters in a string.

```
if (consonant.indexOf(theSent[i][0]) != -1) {
    console.log(theSent[i]);
    console.log("The 1st letter being checked is: " + theSent[i][0]);
} else if (consonant.indexOf(theSent[i][1]) != -1) {
    console.log(theSent[i]);
    console.log("The 2nd letter being checked is: " + theSent[i][1]);
}
```

```js
var vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
var consonant = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

doubleConsonate();

function doubleConsonate() { // add the sent as a parameter
  var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", "a", "few", "more", "smile", "its", "a", "string"];
  console.log("the word or phrase: " + theSent);
  var consonantCount;
  for (var i = 0; i < theSent.length; i++) {
    if (consonant.indexOf(theSent[i][0]) != -1) {
      console.log(theSent[i]);
      console.log("The 1st letter being checked is: " + theSent[i][0]);
    } else if (consonant.indexOf(theSent[i][1]) != -1) {
      console.log(theSent[i]);
      console.log("The 2nd letter being checked is: " + theSent[i][1]);
    }
  }
  console.log(theSent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  You honestly exceeded my expectations!  I also learned a thing or two!

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not entirely sure if I got your question right. If you want to find all double consonants (two of the same letters in direct succession, e.g. "xx" "tt" "dd"):

```
var doubleConsonantsRegex = /([^AaEeIiOoUu\s])\1+/g;

function doubleConsonants() {
    var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", 
                   "a", "few", "more","smile", "its", "a", "string"];
    var sentence = theSent.join(' ');
    var foundOccurences = sentence.match(doubleConsonantsRegex);

    // foundOccurences: ["tt"];
}
```

If your goal is to find two consonants directly after each other but they don't need to be the same (e.g. "st", "wt", "xp", "xx") use a different regex:

```
var doubleConsonantsRegex = /([^AaEeIiOoUu\s]){2}/g; 

function doubleConsonants() {
    var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", 
                   "a", "few", "more","smile", "its", "a", "string"];
    var sentence = theSent.join(' ');
    var foundOccurences = sentence.match(doubleConsonantsRegex);

    // foundOccurences: [ "ct", "ch", "rs", "th", "ch", "sm", "ts", "st", "ng" ];
}
```

If you wanted to find more than two following consonants after each other:

```
var doubleConsonantsRegex = /([^AaEeIiOoUu\s]){2,}/g; 

function doubleConsonants() {
    var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", 
                   "a", "few", "more","smile", "its", "a", "string"];
    var sentence = theSent.join(' ');
    var foundOccurences = sentence.match(doubleConsonantsRegex);

    // foundOccurences: [ "ctt", "ch", "rs", "th", "chz", "sm", "ts", "str", "ng" ]

    var allDoubleConsonants = foundOccurences.reduce(function (newArr, entry) {
        for (var i=0; i<entry.length - 1; i++) {
            newArr.push(entry[i] + entry[i+1]);
        }
        return newArr;
    }, []);

    // allDoubleConsonants: ["ct","tt","ch","rs","th","ch","hz","sm","ts","st","tr","ng"]
}
```

Or, if you want to write it more concise:

```
var doubleConsonantsRegex = /([^AaEeIiOoUu\s]){2,}/g; 
var theSent = ["ctt", "cheers", "to", "your", "mother", "chzek", 
               "a", "few", "more","smile", "its", "a", "string"];

function doubleConsonants(input) {
    return input.join(' ')
        .match(doubleConsonantsRegex)
        .reduce(function (newArr, entry) {
            for (var i=0; i<entry.length - 1; i++) {
                newArr.push(entry[i] + entry[i+1]);
            }
            return newArr;
        }, []);
}

console.log(doubleConsonants(theSent));
```

*Edit1*: Fixed a bug for uppercase vocals. Added example for more than two following consonants

*Edit2*: Adds more concise example

Comment: The second one was the one I was looking for.  Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! Could you accept the answer if this is what you needed? Cheers!

Comment: @JesseM I updated my answer because I noticed a bug: Uppercase vocals were not found by the regex. Additionally, I added another example if you wanted to also find character sequences like this `"ctt"` as this `["ctt"]` or this  `["ct", "tt"]` instead of just `["ct"] // omitting the "tt"`